# How to validate a jquery autocomplete in my Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, validation, google-maps, jquery

My very simple Rails App has a Model with two methods:

:From
:To

I use the awesome (Google Maps API) powered address-rails-picker app for the :to and :from in the form to automplete any location the user types in.

I do however have trouble in writing a validation that forces the user to choose an autocomplete location instead of writing any gibberish the user wants.

I figured I would porablly need to use a callback. Here is my code this far:

```
   class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :from, :to
    validates :from, :presence => true, confirmation: true
    validates :to, :presence => true

    before_validation do
    self.from = from.find_by_address-picker-input(from)
    self.to = to.find_by_address-picker-input(to)

      end
     end
```

Any help would be so much appreciated.

Comment: Its seems this should be a JavaScript side validation and not a Rails?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with Rails only, since the address picker is pure JavaScript. One way I can think of is to add a hidden field acting as a flag. And set this flag if the user manually change the input field. Then validate this flag.